# An inequality for harmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $u:\overline{B^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be harmonic, where $\overline{B^n}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is the closed unit ball. I would like to prove that
$$
\int_{B_1} |Du|^2\leq \int_{\partial B_1} |\partial_{\tau}u|^2,
$$
where $\partial_{\tau}u$ is the tangential derivative of $u$. I tried to use both the Gauss-Green theorem and to write the Laplacian in spherical coordinates, but I always get stuck.

---

Here are some correct but apparently useless computations.

Using the Gauss-Green formula we get
$$
\begin{equation}
0=\int_{B_1} u\Delta u =-\int_{B_1}|Du|^2+\int_{\partial {B_1}}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}.
\end{equation}
$$
The expression of the Laplacian in spherical coordinates is
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
0=\Delta u=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2} +\frac{n-1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+ \frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{\partial B_1} u\\
=\frac{1}{r^{n-1}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^{n-1}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r})+ \frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{\partial B_1} u,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
Integrating this against $u$ and noting that $\partial_{\tau}u=1/r\partial_{\theta}u$ we find the same expression as before (obviously)
$$
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\begin{aligned}
0=-\int_{\partial B_1} \int_0^1|\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}|^2 r^{n-1}+\int_{\partial B_1}u \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}-\int_0^1r^{n-3}\int_{\partial B_1}|\partial_{\theta}u|^2(r\theta)\\
=-\int_{B_1} |\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}|^2 +\int_{\partial B_1}u \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}-\int_{ B_1}|\partial_{\tau}u|^2\\
=-\int_{B_1}|Du|^2+\int_{\partial {B_1}}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: Crossposted to math.overflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435728/an-inequality-for-harmonic-functions/435757#435757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an open, bounded subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$ with $C^1$ boundary and $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\overline \Omega)$, the *Rellich-Pohozaev identity* is \begin{align*}\int_\Omega (x \cdot \nabla u) \Delta u \, dx &= \int_{\partial \Omega} (\partial_\nu u)(x\cdot \nabla u) \, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x - \frac 12 \int_{\partial \Omega} \vert \nabla u \vert^2 (x\cdot \nu) \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x  + \frac {n-2}2 \int_\Omega \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx 
\end{align*} where $\nu$ is the outward pointing unit normal, $\partial_\nu u :=  \nabla u \cdot \nu$, and $\mathcal H^{n-1}_x$ is $(n-1)$-Hausdorff measure. For a proof, see Theorem 2.1.8 in [Elliptic partial differential equations from an elementary viewpoint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.07941) by Dipierro and Valdinoci (they prove it with Dirichlet boundary conditions, but the proof is the same).

Suppose that $n \geqslant 3$,  $\Omega = B_1$, and $\Delta u =0$ in $B_1$.  Then $\nu = x$, so it follows that \begin{align*}0&= \int_{\partial B_1} (\partial_\nu u)^2\, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x - \frac 12 \int_{\partial B_1} \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x  + \frac {n-2}2 \int_{B_1} \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx .
\end{align*} Moreover, by orthogonality of the tangent space and $\nu$, $\vert \nabla u \vert^2 = \vert \partial_\tau u \vert^2 + (\partial_\nu u)^2$, so \begin{align*}
\int_{B_1} \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx &= \frac 2 {n-2} \bigg (\frac 12 \int_{\partial B_1} \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x - \int_{\partial B_1} (\partial_\nu u)^2\, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x\bigg ) \\
&= \frac 2 {n-2} \bigg (\frac 12 \int_{\partial B_1} \vert \partial_\tau u \vert^2 \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x - \frac 12\int_{\partial B_1} (\partial_\nu u)^2\, d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x\bigg ) \\
&\leqslant \frac 1 {n-2}  \int_{\partial B_1} \vert \partial_\tau u \vert^2 \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}_x .
\end{align*} In particular, $\frac 1{n-2} \leqslant 1$, which gives the result.

I'm not sure about the case $n=2$, I'd have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Thank you, I like this answer a lot. The case $n=2$ has been dealt by user @Kostya_I on math.overflow where I crossposted this question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435728/an-inequality-for-harmonic-functions/435757#435757).